# check id on table 'a' if it's same like 'fornkey' on table 'b' get the title from table 'a'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hi I have two tables one is topic_dialogue and the second table is topic_dialogue_comments

table topic_dialogue has column id and table topic_dialogue_comments has column fornkey

all I need here is if table topic_dialogue.id = table topic_dialogue_comments.fornkey

display the title of the table topic_dialogue.id

I have this code but it displays the count of the rows in table topic_dialogue_comments

I just need to display the title of the table topic_dialogue.id one time

```
<?php

    //$getComments="SELECT * FROM `topic_dialogue` AS q LEFT JOIN `topic_dialogue_comments` AS i ON (q.id = i.fornkey);";
    $getComments="SELECT *, fornkey FROM topic_dialogue, topic_dialogue_comments WHERE topic_dialogue.id=topic_dialogue_comments.fornkey";
    $QgetComments=$db->query($getComments)or die($db->error);
    if($QgetComments->num_rows>0){  

?>
<p span class="imroveBlueFonts">mange</p>
<br />


<table width="550" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="3" dir="rtl">
  <tr>
    <td width="257" align="center" bgcolor="#666666" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">title</td>
    <td width="86" align="center" bgcolor="#666666" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">date</td>
    <td width="48" align="center" bgcolor="#666666" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">comments</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  while($tr=$QgetComments->fetch_object()){
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $tr->topic_title ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $tr->topic_date ?></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="index.php?c=4&cp=1&topic=6&comm=<?php //echo $got ?>">view comments</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
    }
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

just now I get for Ex. I have subject1 in table 'a' and it has 3 comments in table 'b' it displays subject1 3 times.

what I need is just put it one time

any help

Comment: seems like **distinct** should be here ? ? ?

Comment: I just get results as if  I have subject1 in table 'topic_dialogue' and 5 comments on table 'topic_dialogue_comments' I get subject1 5 times I need it to display 1 time as if there is another one subject2 and has 3 comments it will appear also one time and when users click on the title he will see all the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change query like this :

```
$getComments="SELECT DISTINCT topic_title , topic_date  
FROM topic_dialogue, topic_dialogue_comments     
WHERE topic_dialogue.id=topic_dialogue_comments.fornkey    
GROUP BY  topic_title , topic_date";
```

Comment: really it worked fine please send me any reference to DISTINCT and really I thank you very much for the help FaceOfJock

Comment: مرحبا أخي check this :http://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php